# Type with unknown number of properties together with a property of type Record<string, string>

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a type for a React component. There are two known properties: `foo` of type `string` and `bar` of type `Record<string, string>`. It also need to accept an unknown number of properties of type `string`. Getting the type working is no problem but when the component is used, TypeScript is complaining:

```
Type '{ foo: string; bar: Record<string, string>; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string>'.
  Property 'bar' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'Record<string, string>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

The types are declared as following:

```js
type A = {
  foo: string;
  bar: Record<string, string>;
};

type B = A & Record<string, string>;
```

and the component is used like so:

```js
<Component
  foo="name"
  bar={{ bar: 'bar' }}
  {...{ baz: 'baz' }} // can be any number of unknown properties
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you can do this with a type definition. This index signature is not compatible with the key `bar`, and although TS allows such constructs, I don't know that they can actually be used directly for type checking.

You can use a mapped type to procedurally check the fields though:

```js
const Component = <P extends CheckProps<P>>(props: P) => null;

type CheckProps<T> = { [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof A ? A[K] : string }
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOAQTgF44BvUuOTCCALjgGcYUYADsA5gG52cAEYoofZGmgATADyDh4gDQChosQD4pAXymllIwXADCuSCKQj4zNQAU4SAB4wnK-rYAFkhoANZuOGD87oaGABRgkfx8bgCUTIZwIgCuADa55lQ0QSHhSWoAKpnMLHAA2gDScKJwoUiUEJhwFQC6fE3eviL+re2d9HAA-PSNPXB8mgZwJuSW1nJQTHBx6YyZcWp24BCOztJcEIz4IiggSGQcG4wstRt8+Bv4yyscLAB0ANeKAAXu85MCviYTHAAPQwuBoFAiWS0JGULLZEAyJCbcbZEShEQQADuyMSEBosGASH4pBhhlSQA)